# fscanf reading newline character

Tags: c, scanf

I have been slowly tracking down my error for my program. I have narrowed it down to this. 
I have a user input

`fscanf(stdin, "%c %c %d", &car, &dir, &amount);`

the first time I access it it works fine, correctly reading in the values. The second time in the loop it reads a `\n` into car instead of the char I give it. it then reads what should have been in car into dir. amount reads correctly. As car is passed to other functions for counting I eventually end up with a segfault.

Is it reading in the \n from the previous line or something?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The `"%c"` conversion specifier does not do the usual whitespace trimming.
Try adding a space before the first conversion specifier

```
if (fscanf(stdin, " %c %c %d", &var, &dir, &amount) != 3) { /* error */ }
```

Or, maybe better, read a full line and parse it within your program

```
char buf[1000];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
parse(buf);
```